# Mock filesystem in integration testing

Tags: ruby, linux, unit-testing, rspec, mocking

I'm writing a ruby program that executes some external command-line utilities. How could I mock the filesystem from my rspec tests so that I could easily setup some file hierarchy and verify it after testing. It would also be best to be implemented in ram so that tests would run quickly.

I realize that I may not find a portable solution as my external utilities are native programs interacting directly with operating system file services. Linux is my primary platform and solution for that would suffice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe this won't answer your question directly, but in such cases I tend to create a temporary directory during test setup and remove it on teardown. Of course you also have to ensure the application writes to this temporary directory. I always have a configuration option defining destination directory that I can overwrite during testing.

When it comes to assertions I use plain `File.exist?` or `File.directory?`, but of course you can create your own wrappers around it. If you need some initial state you can build a directory that can be used as a fixture and will be copied to the temporary direcory during test setup.

Comment: This might work with ramdisk filesystem, but I was looking for some more advanced solution.

Comment: Where do you create temporary directories? Is it safe to create and delete /tmp/my_test_dir?

Answer (score 40):

Have you checked out [FakeFS](http://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) or <strike>MockFS</strike>?

*Note: The original link to MockFS doesn't work. It [looks like](https://rubygems.org/gems/mockfs) it's no longer being maintained.*

Comment: Really nice, Rspec helper shipped!

Comment: Incredibly easy to set up. Highly recommended to anyone scrolling by. For instance, for simple reading and writing this would be enough (it was certainly more than adequate to test my file logging module): https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs#temporarily-faking-the-fs

Answer (score 6):

You can create a big file (size of you dummy disk) and mount the file as a [loop-back device](http://www.csulb.edu/~pnguye11/loopbackDev.html). You can create any filesystem and directory structure on this device.
You can create 2 of them and make even simple diff compare to ensure data integrity after tests.
I hope i understand you requirements correctly since i don't sure why simple ramdisk solution is not good enough.
[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_image_emulator) might be relevant as well.

Comment: Damn, this is a real geeky answer, but probably not for most Rubyists. However, it should work. I'll up vote it for geek factor. :-)

Comment: i will take this as a compliment :)

Comment: You could take this thread one step further with unionfs:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS